# Remember Last QLineEdit data

Tags: qt, qlineedit

My App takes input for Id and Birthdate in QLineEdit and sends the form data as http post request.
Is it possible for the last entered input to stay when app is closed and then restarted??

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Use [QSettings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html)

For example:

```
QSettings settings(QSettings::UserScope);
settings.setValue("Birthdate", date);
```

then...

```
QSettings settings(QSettings::UserScope);
dateLineEdit->setText(settings.value("Birthdate").toString());
```

See the documentation regarding scope and file formats and determine what usage suits your needs best.